# Gas too low for transaction | Arbitrum

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, ethereumjs, arbitrum

I am trying to send a transaction with ethers.js. All looks fine but I get this error anytime I start my app to development.

The error on my IDE:

```
Error sending tx: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":247,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\
"message\":\"intrinsic gas too low\"}}\n", 
error={"code":-32000}, requestBody="
{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\": ..........
```

I have this as my tx parameters:

```
const tx = await burnWallet.sendTransaction({
      to: flashbotsBeerFund,
      gasLimit: 21000,
      gasPrice,
      nonce,
      value: leftovers,
});
``
```

Answer (score 0):

your gas limit is too low - this may satisfy the minimum gas limit, but often due to network activity you need to provide more to push a tx through.

Try 210000 or even 2100000 - it's unlikely all your gas will be used, but it provides the buffer to ensure at least formal processing ( `{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\"` ) is undertaken, even if the tx is to revert.

Comment: ` Error sending tx: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ] (error={"reason":"processing response error","code":"SERVER_ERROR","body":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":462,\"error\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"insufficient funds for gas * price + value: `

Comment: i got that error

Comment: where are you deploying?

Comment: An eth wallet burner bot.

Comment: no, i mean on what network. eth? mainnet? goerli?

Comment: arbitrum network

Comment: and you have enough Eth in your wallet?

Comment: well, the goal is to burn all eth in the wallet. I'm currently using arbitrum testnet.

Comment: you can't burn **all** the eth in the wallet perfectly. Ensure the min eth left is greater than the minimum gas required for transaction. That help?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Arbitrum requires a higher `gasLimit` than other networks for comparable transactions, so a `21000` gas limit may work on Ethereum mainnet, but not on Arbitrum.

Also, make sure you have enough Arbitrum ETH in your wallet to cover the cost of `gasPrice*gasLimit`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same fricking error bro, I fixed it by increasing the gas limit up to 7000000(the maximum gas limit permitted by arbitrum). hope it works out for you too, greetings from argentina. vamo vamo argentina campeones del mundo!